# How to solve dynamic Text view creation not visible in android activity?

Tags: android, dynamic, textview

Here i created 8 text views four for the heading and other four are displaying the content of the sql lite database.I don't know its the necessary for creating text view while executing dynamic text view creation.

Xml file:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="#66C2E0"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
           android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/dat"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                    android:focusable="false"
                android:inputType="date" >


            </EditText>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >



            <Button
                android:id="@+id/search"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Search" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"

             android:stretchColumns="0,1,2,3"
                        android:id="@+id/mt" 
            >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/soi1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="TextView" />


                 <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/woc1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="TextView" />


                  <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/desc1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="TextView" />


                   <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/amount1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="TextView" />


            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                  <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/soi"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="TextView" />


                 <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/woc"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="TextView" />


                  <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/desc"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="TextView" />


                   <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/amount"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="TextView" />



            </TableRow>


        </TableLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

java class:

I created dynamic textview creation it doesn't display anything in activity not even display the heading,But i exeute using Log,it displays the exact output in logcat.

```
     search.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                addheaders();
                adddata();

            }


                    });
    }



    protected void addheaders() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         tr = new TableRow(this);

            tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

             soi1 = new TextView(this);
            soi1.setText("Income Source");
            soi1.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            soi1.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD);
            soi1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            soi1.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 0);
            tr.addView(soi1);  // Adding textView to tablerow.


            /** Creating another textview **/
             woc1 = new TextView(this);
            woc1.setText("Cash Mode");
            woc1.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            woc1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            woc1.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 0);
            woc1.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD);
            tr.addView(woc1); // Adding textView to tablerow.


            /** Creating another textview **/
             desc1 = new TextView(this);
            desc1.setText("Description");
            desc1.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            desc1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            desc1.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 0);
            desc1.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD);
            tr.addView(desc1); // Adding textView to tablerow.


            /** Creating another textview **/
             amount1 = new TextView(this);
            amount1.setText("Cash Mode");
            amount1.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            amount1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            amount1.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 0);
            amount1.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD);
            tr.addView(amount1); // Adding textView to tablerow.


            // Add the TableRow to the TableLayout
            tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        }

    protected void adddata() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

Database db=new Database(Reportdwr.this);
SQLiteDatabase sb=db.getReadableDatabase();

 Cursor cus=sb.rawQuery("select * from income",null);

 cus.moveToFirst();
 for(int i=0;i<cus.getCount();i++)

     {
     if(cus.getString(2).toString().equalsIgnoreCase(dat.getText().toString()))
     {


         tr = new TableRow(this);
         tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                 LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                 LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


         /** Creating a TextView to add to the row **/
         soi = new TextView(this);

         soi.setText(cus.getString(0));
         soi.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
         soi.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
         soi.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD);
         soi.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

         soi.setTextSize(17);
         //tr.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);
         soi.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
         soi.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         tr.addView(soi); 
         Log.i("output",cus.getString(0));


         woc = new TextView(this);
         woc.setText(cus.getString(1));
         woc.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
         woc.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD);
         woc.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
         woc.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
         tr.addView(woc); 


         desc = new TextView(this);
         desc.setText(cus.getString(4));
         desc.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
         desc.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD);
         desc.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
         desc.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
         tr.addView(desc); 


         amount = new TextView(this);
         amount.setText(cus.getString(5));
         amount.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
         amount.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD);
         amount.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
         amount.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
         tr.addView(amount); 

         tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                 LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                 LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


     }
     cus.moveToNext();
}
}
}
```

Comment: Why are you creating those dynamic layouts in the first place? What is tl in your code and how do you instantiate it?

Comment: tl represents table layout